# Laravel Mix | Bootstrap DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, sass, laravel-mix

I install bootstrap using npm and use scss to import it
but when I try to compile,It just show endless warnings

```
npm install bootstrap
```

app.scss file

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

and when I run dev

```
npm run dev
```

then I see Endless loop with this warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($spacer, 4)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

    ╷
253 │   1: $spacer / 4,
    │      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_variables.scss 253:6  @import
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss 11:9    @import
    resources\css\app.scss 2:9                         root stylesheet
```

My webpack.mix

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/css/app.scss', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

Answer (score 18):

As Brian Hannay mentioned in the comments, to downgrade to a specific version of a package, in this case SASS, you should:

1. change `"sass": "^1.33.0",` to `"sass": "1.32.13",` in package.json.
2. delete package-lock.json
3. delete node_modules folder
4. run npm install

Note that this will update all of your other packages within NPM. If you do not want to do that, simply remove "sass" from your package-lock.json and that particular folder within node_modules.

Comment: This does not work for me for some reason :-(

Comment: Can also use `"sass": "~1.32.13",` in case they release any more `1.32.*` versions (probably unlikely though).

Answer (score 14):

As described in the [SASS documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div), you can use the Sass migrator to automatically update your stylesheets to use math.div().

`$ npm install -g sass-migrator`

`$ sass-migrator division **/*.scss`

Comment: Note that this will change files in the node_modules! ..which is not something you would really want.
Nice one for updating your own code though

Comment: Nothing to migrate! That's the message I get :-/

Comment: @BluE nah, "You can't fix font-awesome without moving it entirely into your project" is the message I get.

Comment: Hilarious! This `sass-migrator` converts `something / 2` to `something * 0.5`.

Answer (score 7):

Add quietDeps to your sass-loader config.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css', {
  sassOptions: {
    quietDeps: true,
  },
})
```

Comment: This don't seems to work. I still see all warnings

Comment: @realtebo It *does* work. It bears mention that a) this option does not _eliminate_ the warnings entirely; it merely reduces the number of times each warning is emitted to 5 instances per feature, and b) the underlying Dart Sass version must be at least 1.34.0, in which this switch was introduced. Finally, the release notes in the documentation seem to be incorrect in that they state `Cap deprecation warnings at 5 per feature by default.`, but that does not seem to be the case _unless_ this option is specified.

Comment: thanks. I ended up using a npm packet patcher so we fixed by our own and we can still using git and committed the patches for ours developer

Comment: Contrary to the comments above I can confirm this completely quietened the warnings for me.

Answer (score 2):

As they are only warnings until Dart Sass 2.0.0 comes through i assume at this point you could ignore and wait on Bootstrap to update their package with the new division synthax math.div(...)

Got the same basic setup running, getting the same warnings.

Comment: Waiting out an endless loop isn't much of a solution. I've addressed the endless output by redirecting it. `npm run dev 2>/dev/null` works for me. Apparently you can also downgrade to `saas <= 1.32.*`, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: @BrianHannay Yes just downgrade, it removes the error and works.  Use `npm install sass@1.32.13 --save-dev` to write sass package version to `package.json` and `npm install sass@1.32.13` to downgrade.  There is a French speaking guy on Y Tube that explains bootstrap 5 setup quite nicely (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHD7sEvChaU).  Did not understand a word he said, but definitely what he was doing.

Comment: I ended up using a npm packet patcher so we fixed by our own and we can still using git and committed the patches for ours developer

Answer (score -1):

I cleared the warnings by:

1. deleting my node modules.
2. run npm cache clean --force
3. run npm install.

Comment: 1. I didn't downvoted yout, but 2. it will not resolve the problem